# Insert a constraint for two columns in sql

Tags: database, sqlite, foreign-keys, create-table, referential-integrity

Hi everyone I created this table for a database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS compositions (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        id_product INTEGER REFERENCES products(id),
        id_receipt INTEGER REFERENCES receipt(id),
        quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
        price FLOAT NOT NULL,
        id_user VARCHAR REFERENCES users(id),
        CONSTRAINT CHK_price_quantity CHECK (price > 0 AND quantity > 0)
    );
```

I would like to insert a constraint that, for a given id_receipt, the id_user must be always the same but I don't know how to implement it.
Could someone give a help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no id_client column in the table. Edit your question to explain better what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant id_user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this requirement the column `id_user` should not be defined in the table `compositions`.

It makes more sense to store it in the table `receipt`, since each `id_receipt` is related to 1 and only 1 `id_user`.

This way you have `id_receipt` as a foreign key in `compositions` and through this column you can get (by a join) all the info that you want from `receipt`, like the `id_user`.

Comment: Thanks! So it was probably a problem of bad designing